# Form not submitting the input elements to php file

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form that is half way hidden when the page loads and when the user clicks on the first input box the rest of the form displays below it... I now try to submit the file to the php page and just echoing out what the input elements contained... however, this is not working... I have a feeling that this is because half of the form is hidden when the page loads...

here is the code for the form

```
<form action='new-question.php' method='post' id='new-question-form'>
   <input type='text' name='title' class='shown-input' placeholder='Ask a new question'>
   <!-- HIDDEN UNLESS CLICKED -->
   <div class='hidden-until-click'>
      <textarea name='details' placeholder="Enter your question details..."></textarea>
      <button type='button' id='upload-question' class='btn'>
         <img src='assets/images/css_images/upload.png'>
         upload
      </button>
      <input type='submit' name='submit-question' id='submit-question' value='Go!' class='bttn bttn-blue tiny'>
   </div>
   <!-- END HIDDEN UNTIL CLICKED-->
</form>
```

and my php file

```
 <?php
     if (isset($_POST['submit-question'])){
        echo $_POST['title'];
     } else {
         echo "Nothing submitted;
     }
    ?>
```

it just keeps saying nothing submitted....

HERE is how i hide the div:

```
$(".hidden-until-click").hide();
```

and then show it like this

```
$(".widget.small form#new-question-form .hidden-until-click").show();
```

HERE IS var_dump($_POST):

```
array(2) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["details"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: what does it print when you var_dump($_POST); ?

Comment: I've tried your code and except for the missing double quotes at the end of "Nothing submitted", it seems to be working fine. However, nothing is hidden at the moment. How do you hide/show the elements? Is it via CSS or JS? If it's via JS, can you please post the code?

Comment: i just put that up.. i hide when document is ready and then show when first input element is shown... i was originally doing it by visibility but that was not working either

Comment: another thing to note is that I am submitting the file using jquery-forms.js $("#myform").ajaxForm(function(data){});

Comment: Thanks. var_dump looks ok, did you fill in any of the fields?

Comment: yes i did... i just don't know why it isn't noticing the submit button post

Comment: I get all vars, including submit-question button even when the form is hidden and I click Enter. So the problem is probably related to something that you didn't post up there. Can you setup a fully working JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine for me!

You only problem you had was

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit-question'])){
        echo $_POST['title'];
     } else {
         echo "Nothing submitted;
     }
```

You have to close `echo "Nothing submitted;` like this `echo "Nothing submitted";`

Comment: yea i fixed that. must have deleted that when formatting for the question :P

Comment: Okay, then checkout why $_POST['submit-question'] is not 'posting' - might be a problem with your ajaxForm

Comment: or just check if(isset($_POST['title'])){ echo $_POST['title']; } else {echo 'Please Fill title';}

Answer (score 0):

try after putting this hidden field inside the form

```
<input name="submit-question" type="hidden" value="yes"/>
```